# Unable to parse database values from selected value in drop down list to textbox using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to parse data from the database to the text boxes on my database. However, after scrolling through numerous questions here, I cannot find a solution that works for me. here are my codes:

Edit.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<head>
<title>Kinder App - Edit</title>
</head>
<style> body {background-image: url("/KinderApp/images/Untitled-1.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;}]
  header   {color:black; background-color:white;}
  footer    {color:green; background-color:lightgrey; }
  h1 {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:50px; }
  h6 {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:15px; color: red; font-weight:bold; }
  span {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size: 15px; color:blue;  }
  </style>
<link href="general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;


tt=display_c();
 }

function showModule(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("id").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
        {
          document.getElementById("name").value = data.mname;
          document.getElementById("desc").value = data.mdesc;
          document.getElementById("icon").value = data.micon;
          document.getElementById("vers").value = data.mvers;
          document.getElementById("loca").value = data.mloca;
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getmodule.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body onload=display_ct();>
<center><header>Kinder App</header></center>
<br>
<center><h1>Edit</h1></center>
<br>
<form action="edit_file.php" class="dropzone"><center><h2>Drag and Drop to upload</h2>
<br><h6>WARNING: uploading files with the same file name will oveerwrite the uploaded one.</h6></center></form>

<form action="edit_file.php" method="POST">

<center><table border="1" width="50%">
   <tr>
     <td><center>Module ID:</center></td>
     <td><center>
        <select id="id" name="mID" class="quform-tooltip chosen-select" onchange="showModule(this.value)">";
         <?php 
         define("DB_USER", "root");
         define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
         define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
         define("DB_NAME", "kp2admin");
         //echo '<select name="mID">';
         $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
       $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT Module_ID FROM module ORDER BY Module_ID");
       if ($result != null) {
            echo '<option value="" selected>Select</option>';
            $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
               $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
               $mId = $row['Module_ID'];
                echo '<option value="' .$mId. '">' .$mId. '</option>';
           }
           
              
          //echo '</select>';
       }
       mysqli_close($dbc);
       ?>
       
    </select>
  </center></td>
 </tr>
     
 
<tr>
     <td><center>Module Name:</center></td> 
     <td><center><input type="text" id="name" name="mName"/></center></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td><center>Description:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="desc" name="mDesc"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Icon:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="icon" name="icon"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Version:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="vers" name="mVersion"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Location:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="loca" name="mLocate"/></center></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</center> 
       
        <center><input type="submit" value="Update Details"></center>
</form>
    <p><center><a href="list_modules.php">See all files</a></center></p>
<p align="right"><b><span id='ct' ></span></b></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="KinderAppAdmin.html" method="POST">
<input type="image" src="/KinderApp/images/sds.png" name="image" width="61" height="49">
</form>
<footer><center>Copyright © All Rights Reserved</center></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

getmodule.php

```html
<?php 
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "kp2admin");
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$sql="SELECT Module_Name, Description, Icon, Version, Location FROM module WHERE Module_ID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);


$info = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
 $moduleName = $row['Module_Name'];
 $description = $row['Description'];
 $icon = $row['Icon'];
 $version = $row['Version'];
 $location = $row['Location'];
 $info[] = array( 'mID' => $moduleId, 'mname' => $moduleName, 'mdesc' => $description, 'micon' => $icon, 'mvers' => $version, 'mloca' => $location );
 
 
}
echo json_encode($info);

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

As you can see I am trying to parse each column to a respective text box, but am unable to do so. I am using JSON to parse the data but to no avail. Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

When parsing data, firebug reports of this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icCz6.png

Comment: if possible please post what json data you received from ajax request and check your console using firebug to check whether you are getting any js errors while parsing.

Comment: what you have posted is error from console (yes it was helpful) but what Atul asked for is the request/response in network monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days of trouble shooting, I found the solution to my own question.

Here are the correct codes:

Edit.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<head>
<title>Kinder App - Edit</title>
</head>
<style> body {background-image: url("/KinderApp/images/Untitled-1.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;}]
  header   {color:black; background-color:white;}
  footer    {color:green; background-color:lightgrey; }
  h1 {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:50px; }
  h6 {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:15px; color: red; font-weight:bold; }
  span {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size: 15px; color:blue;  }
  </style>
<link href="general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;


tt=display_c();
 }

function showModule(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("id").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
        {
         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          document.getElementById("name").value = data[i].mname;
          document.getElementById("desc").value = data[i].mdesc;
          document.getElementById("icon").value = data[i].micon;
          document.getElementById("vers").value = data[i].mvers;
          document.getElementById("loca").value = data[i].mloca;
         }
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getmodule.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function editModule(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("id").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
        {
         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          document.getElementById("name").value = data[i].mname;
          document.getElementById("desc").value = data[i].mdesc;
          document.getElementById("icon").value = data[i].micon;
          document.getElementById("vers").value = data[i].mvers;
          document.getElementById("loca").value = data[i].mloca;
         }
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","edit_file.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body onload=display_ct();>
<center><header>Kinder App</header></center>
<br>
<center><h1>Edit</h1></center>
<br>
<form action="edit_file.php" class="dropzone"><center><h2>Drag and Drop to upload</h2>
<br><h6>WARNING: uploading files with the same file name will oveerwrite the uploaded one.</h6></center></form>

<form action="edit_file.php" method="POST">

<center><table border="1" width="50%">
   <tr>
     <td><center>Module ID:</center></td>
     <td><center>
        <select id="id" name="mID" class="quform-tooltip chosen-select" onchange="showModule(this.value)">";
         <?php 
         define("DB_USER", "root");
         define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
         define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
         define("DB_NAME", "kp2admin");
         //echo '<select name="mID">';
         $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
       $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT Module_ID FROM module ORDER BY Module_ID");
       if ($result != null) {
            echo '<option value="" selected>Select</option>';
            $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
               $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
               $mId = $row['Module_ID'];
                echo '<option value="' .$mId. '">' .$mId. '</option>';
           }
           
              
          //echo '</select>';
       }
       mysqli_close($dbc);
       ?>
       
    </select>
  </center></td>
 </tr>
     
 
<tr>
     <td><center>Module Name:</center></td> 
     <td><center><input type="text" id="name" name="mName"/></center></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td><center>Description:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="desc" name="mDesc"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Icon:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="icon" name="icon"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Version:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="vers" name="mVersion"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Location:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="loca" name="mLocate"/></center></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</center> 
       
        <center><input type="submit" value="Update Details"></center>
</form>
    <p><center><a href="list_modules.php">See all files</a></center></p>
<p align="right"><b><span id='ct' ></span></b></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="KinderAppAdmin.html" method="POST">
<input type="image" src="/KinderApp/images/sds.png" name="image" width="61" height="49">
</form>
<footer><center>Copyright © All Rights Reserved</center></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

getmodules.php:

```html
<?php 
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "kp2admin");
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$sql="SELECT Module_Name, Description, Icon, Version, Location FROM module WHERE Module_ID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);


$info = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
 $moduleName = $row['Module_Name'];
 $description = $row['Description'];
 $icon = $row['Icon'];
 $version = $row['Version'];
 $location = $row['Location'];
 $info[] = array( 'mname' => $moduleName, 'mdesc' => $description, 'micon' => $icon, 'mvers' => $version, 'mloca' => $location );
 
 
}
echo json_encode($info);

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Apparently, I had an extra declaration in the array. Thanks to Cerlin and Atul for the comments. It helped a lot with my issues. Thanks again